# How to create a Google Forms in a specific Google Drive folder using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-forms, google-api-python-client

I can't manage to find a way to create a Google Forms in a specific directory.

All the forms I create are located at the top level of my Google Drive.

```
form = {
    "info": {
        "title": "My new form"
    },
}
# Prints the details of the sample form
result = form_service.forms().create(body=form).execute()
print(result)
```

I have tried to add the `parents` keyword but it doesn't work as expected (it is not listed in the Google Forms API documentation)

Is there a way to do that?

I can only think of using the form id created at the top level and assign a new parent target folder id.

I searched the documentation but I couldn't find a way to specify the parent folder at form creation.